# How to detect new mail message with imap

Tags: imap, mailkit, mimekit

Using imap I can see that on the server there are new messages that are not in my local cache. However how to know if those new messages are actually just received and never seen by the user, instead of messages moved from another folder into Inbox?

Comment: Each message carries an `internaldate` which is set at the time a message is delivered/inserted, and is preserved by `copy` and `move`. The delivery agent or inserter can set a misleading time, but in general _newish internaldate and not flagged as \seen_ is a good test.

Comment: yeah, that will work, thanks!